# My device isn't booting after moving an app to /system and then uninstalling it

Tags: boot-loop

I have Huawei p8 lite ALE-L21 dual sim running Lollipop. I downloaded an app called Game Killer which I converted to a system app.  It didn't seem to work so then I deleted it by using link2sd. It asked me to reboot the device, and afterward it was stuck on the Huawei welcome screen. I thought it would need some time then open, but it's been like this since yesterday. I tried so many ROMs but non are working. Does anyone know how to I could fix my device?

Comment: Could you add more details about what ROMs you tried, and how you installed them?  Flashing the stock ROM ought to have fixed this issue.

Comment: Did you try to hard reset your phone after installing the ROM? Turn your phone off and press volume up and power key until the device starts. Then factory reset it. It may help.

Answer (score 0):

First, plug it into a computer and see if you can connect to it and pull stuff you might need off of it, although I would hope you have photos and contacts already backed up. If it won't connect to your computer, I'm not sure what to do about that.

Does your phone have a recovery menu? I don't know what ROM you're running, but [this page here](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/use-recovery-mode-android/) details how to boot into it, or find specific instructions for your ROM or phone, which I would expect to be in the manual or online. If you can get here, try resetting to factory settings.

If it did connect to your computer, wipe it clean through the recovery menu or otherwise and flash either your ROM or stock on to it.

If you can't connect it to a computer for one reason or another, you might be able to load a ROM onto your SD card and flash that from recovery, but no guarantees on this.

And if you haven't, try restarting it once more.